# Do @Setter and @Getter annotations of lombok can be thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, lombok

I have a problem with my class SessionCanal, when I use in a Web Service the attribute "idSession" is changed when multiple requests come in, I want to know if the Setters and Getters can be thread-safe (synchronized them in some way)

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SesionCanal implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 360569424947712753L;

    @Getter @Setter private String idSesion;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 19):

You can use:

```
@Getter(onMethod_={@Synchronized}) @Setter(onMethod_={@Synchronized}) 
private String idSesion;
```

with Lombok @Synchronized

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No.

By default, servlets are not thread safe, and getter/setter methods (auto-generated by annotations, or manually coded) are not thread safe.  if you need read/write access, and you also need thread safety, then you need to synchronize access.

Look at [Handling threading issues](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/817-1833-10/pwasrvlt.html) in the Oracle documentation.

Personally, I prefer to hand-code getter and setter methods.  In part, for situations like this.

Comment: Thanks @FoggyDay I think that exist something annotation for support thread-safe in lombok, then I need to change the class for use hand-code getter and setter methods.

Answer (score 0):

Back it with an `AtomicReference`; as long as only one field is changing, it'll do the job. You'll have to write your own getter and setter.